Explicit parallelization of an exotic sphere
I asked this question on MathStackExchange a week ago (see here), but, despite a few upvotes, I received no comments or answers. Ideally, I would love a detailed answer, but a yes/no would do the job! Let me spell out the question. 
I recently got interested in Milnor's exotic spheres in dimension 7, and learnt that they are parallelizable. This is a known fact - see this other quesion on MathOverflow for a good discussion and some references.
My question is whether the explicit form of this parallelization is also known, as it is the case for the ordinary 7-sphere. If not, is there a straightforward way of finding an expression for this vector field? 
Thanks in advance!

These are Brieskorn spheres which are known to be parallelizable in dimension 7. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere?wprov=sfti1#Brieskorn_spheres  They are stably parallelizable, since they bound a parallelizable manifold. In dimension 7, stably parallelizable manifolds are parallelizable. Maybe one can make these proofs explicit enough to find a parallelization. See the end of section 3 of  http://www.numdam.org/item/SB_1966-1968__10__13_0.pdf and section 5 of  https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.12149

That's very useful, thank you. I referred to Milnor's spheres because I was hoping to have an answer in the context of their construction as S^3 bundles over S^4. Are you aware of any discussion from that perspective?
